# How to find a missing closed square bracket in a string

Tags: php, string

Lets say I have this document with references in square bracket.

`Test alpha [1] another beta 2] some huge gamma errors [3] delta airlines [4[`

When I parse it I can get if a square bracket is missing with counting strings with `substr_count`. But how can I get a position in the document or string of the missing closed or opening square bracket(s) are?

Any idea?

Comment: I don't see how you can possibly determine that. E.g., should it be `[2]` or `[beta 2]` or `[another beta 2]`?

Comment: It should check for and if this fails, then I need the position of the Failure. `Test alpha [1] another beta [2] some huge gamma errors [3] delta airlines [4]`

Comment: Is the string in the brackets always only one single character?

Comment: No. It could be more then one and not even Number. I have some strings like `[see help file]` or `[see section 12B or 12.1 C[` where the closed square bracket is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do two regular two expression searches for
left bracket [
then a wild card that matches any number of characters,
then another left bracket [

That will find strings like [123ABC[

Then repeat the search using the right bracket to find strings like ]123ABC]

This will only work if your document does not contain items in nested brackets like  [FirstString[SecondString]]

Also because regular expressions use the right and left bracket to signify a grouping you must use the \ before your left and right bracket to distinguish it from the group delimiters in the regular expression.

[a-zA-Z0-9]* is the regular expression substring that matches multiple lower case, upper case or numeric characters

[[a-zA-Z0-9]*[ so this should be the regular expression for the first search
][a-zA-Z0-9]*]

The Notepad++ editor has a regular expression search if you want to test the expressions there.